# How disable SCL SECURE WARNING just for a function call and not globaly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

According to MSDN about [_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985974.aspx):

> Calling any one of the potentially unsafe methods in the Standard C++ Library will result in [Compiler Warning (level 3) C4996](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx). To disable this warning, define the macro _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in your code:
>
> ```
> #define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
> ```

it is also posible to disable the warning like this:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
```

**but ...  by using any of this approaches you can disable the warning globaly, I want to doit localy, for instance:**

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
some_string.copy(str, some_string.length());
// #pragma warning(enable:4996)   There is something outhere like this?
```

There is something like above code outhere?

Comment: MMMM I'm wondering why the down vote.

Comment: It's `#pragma warning(default:...)` that's the closest "opposite" to `#pragma warning(disable:...)`, although as its name implies it doesn't actual enable a warning that is off by default.

Comment: @CharlesBailey `#pragma warning(default:...)` does not remove any modification to the warning status glabaly?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @CharlesBailey  My bad, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using the syntax:

```
#pragma warning( push )  // Stores the current warning state for every warning.

#pragma warning( pop )   // pops the last warning state pushed onto the 
                         // stack. Any changes that you made to the warning
                         // state between push and pop are undone.
```

is posible to modify and resotre the warning configuration localy.

So, following the example of the question, you could disable and then enable again the warning:

```
#pragma warning(push)                // save the warning conf status.
#pragma warning(disable:4996)        // disable specific warning.
// ...                               // you could disable more than one.
target.copy(str, target.length());   // call 
#pragma warning(pop)                 // restore previous warning conf.
```

As Charles Bailey pointed out in the comments you could also use:

```
#pragma warning(default: ...)
```

but you have to take into account that if the state of the warning is disabled by default, this will not restore such warning to be enabled again.

For instace: Let be n a warning that is disabled by default.

```
// At this point n was enabled.
#pragma warning(disable:n)
// ... some code here
#pragma warning(default:n)   
// n remains disabled. Maybe not what you want.
```

Reference: [MSDN warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx)

Comment: just wondering, `#undefine / code /  #define` could work too?

Comment: I think it would... let me try

Comment: @Amadeus I've tried your idea, but I discover that if you do not write `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before any line of code it doesn't works (whaaaat!!??). So, it doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the try

Comment: @Amadeus my previous conclusion was not quite right, it seems some of the include statements miss with `#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` some how.  But I think that's another question.

Comment: After a bit of thinking I realized it was a silly suggestion. Just undefing / calling / defining will change nothing in code being called, at least not for all possible cases